# Teams - Allow system admins to override accepted answers for questions that are outdated

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

This is specific to teams...

We had a process we documented years ago that changed.  I put a new answer and cannot accept it unless the original question asker accepts it.  That person has changed teams and actually may not be with the company any longer.

Please allow the system admins of the system to select the accepted answer.  I would have thought that would be the default way to do this since they "manage" the site.

Comment: Why not just edit the original answer instead?

Comment: @RobertLongson - There are cases where we want to keep the original in tact as a fall back I'd rather it allow to create a new answer - which I can create a new answer.  My issue is I cannot mark it accepted.  As a system admin/owner I should be able to have that ability to override.  Gotta remember not everyone is a system admin most companies have 1-2 people acting as an admin.

Comment: You can do that too by creating a new answer as a fall back. Copy the original answer in there and then replace the accepted answer. Or just put the fallback at the bottom of the edited answer. All options while you're waiting for this feature request.

Comment: I understand what I can do right now - this request is to better the product for these types of use cases.  To me an admin should have override capability.